# How to arrange text for header, on one line

Tags: html, css

I have a project and I need some text to look like this on my website, I managed to put them on one line, but I can t separate them. How can I do it, what should I use?

Exemple:

Header             link 1 link 2 link 3

(There is space between header and the links, but it doesn t show)

Thank you![
][1]

Comment: Please add your code, maybe a screenshot of what it looks like right now, and what you want it to look like.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We'd love to assist you but we're here to troubleshoot code and you haven't posted any! :( Please consider reading [ask] and posting a [mre] of your code and outlining what you're looking to accomplish so we can help you do it! :)

Comment: Ok I will post after I get home. But I can t post images yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the elements are on a single line, you can use display:flex and the gap property. If you want to pad only one element, give it a margin / padding property (depending on the situation)

> https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox
> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp
> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Comment: Your answer does provide an appropriate solution to the problem but could be improved by including an example.